# WordPress Theme getting stuck in uploading picture

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have developed a custom theme. everything is working perfect but after install the theme i can not upload any picture at the same time clicking button also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happen for including CSS and JavaScript file.
 i was used **`after_setup_theme()`** action instead of **`wp_enqueue_scripts()`**,which is not proper way to include JS and CSS file.

another problem was that to include CSS and JS i used **`wp_enqueue_style()`,** which was wrong.
when i used **`wp_enqueue_style()`** for css and **`wp_enqueue_script()`** for JS then it's work prefect and solve my problem.
here is the code which work for me.   **including JS file:**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_js');
function add_js(){
wp_enqueue_script('nav', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), '', TRUE);
}
```

**including CSS file:**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_css');
function add_css(){
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.css');
}
```